# How can I add new peers to my channel & Organizations?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I hope you're doing great.

I'm a beginner in Hyperledger fabric, and just done with the building your first network samples in the documentation.

Now I'm trying to add new peers to my channel(or to one of 2 Organizations being provided at the first time) but I have no idea how to do it.

I've been looking for how to make it and found out some answers on this website, but I'm still clueless.

So I'd like to ask you to tell me how to add new peers to those in detail if you don't mind.

What should I do in order to make it in the first place? I heard I should modify some files and need to execute some commands. Can I ask you which files and commands should I work on?

I really appreciate your help if you help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the crypto-config.yaml file and add new peers, and then use the command (available in v1.1)

```
./build/bin/cryptogen extend
```

This extends the layout of the certificate tree in crypto-config and adds folders according to the new updated crypto-config.yaml

To add some more peers just edit the following section in the file:

> ```
> Specs:
> #   - Hostname: foo # implicitly "foo.org1.hrl.ibm.il"
> #     CommonName: foo27.org5.hrl.ibm.il # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
> #     SANS:
> #       - "bar.{{.Domain}}"
> #       - "altfoo.{{.Domain}}"
> #       - "{{.Hostname}}.org6.net"
> #   - Hostname: bar
> #   - Hostname: baz
>     - Hostname: vm2
>     - Hostname: vm3
>     - Hostname: vm4
> ```

below the:

> PeerOrgs:

section.

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail? I have no idea what to change and how to change in the crypto-config.yaml file. I would really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

you have to update crypto-config.yaml file and configtx.yaml file. and run again cryptogen tool to generate related certificates.